# Cypress: Optimize way to find the very deep element

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I am trying to check the text inside a span element which is very deep down the dom tree, and I dont want to use a sequence of get/find command to find the text, here is my dom structure looks like:

```
<td>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div></div>
         <div>
           <div>
             <div> </div>
             <span> **target** </span>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div>
     ...
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

thanks for the help

Comment: If you can control the DOM then you can basically add an Id or a data attribute to find it.

Comment: unfortunately I don't have control over the DOM

Comment: Then what I can suggest is if an item has something unique (an Id, a class name, or a tag name) you can narrow down the search by adding that unifier at the beginning of your CSS query.

Comment: can we consider span as unique? if so what would be the command?

Comment: If there is only one span in your entire DOM then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the first `div element` and find by span.

example:

```
const spanEl = cy.get('div').find('span')
```

If the `parent div element` has a CSS class or some unique attribute, it would be easier.

```
const spanEl = cy.get('#attribute-of-div-el').find('span')
```

ref: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Get-vs-Find

Comment: I tried it but got error: `Timed out retrying after 30000ms: Expected to find element: div, but never found it.`

Comment: You should read into [variables in cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Return-Values) @jsantos

Comment: thanks! that solved my problem, the error was coming from a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<span>` has unique text then you'll benefit from using [`cy.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains). It is quite powerful and underused.

```
cy.contains('span', 'Your unique text')
```

you can even use regex

```
cy.contains('span', /your unique text/)
```